# Como acho, em meio a inspeção de uma pagina web, partes de codigo em base64?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Como acho, em meio a inspeção de uma pagina web, partes de coigo em base64?

Comment: É só dar um Ctrl+U na página que vc quer. Depois da um Ctrl+F para abrir a pesquisa, e digita ali "base64" e manda pequisar. Vc deve encontrar algo do tipo `<img id="myid" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...>` Mas lembro que base64 não precisa ser usado exclusivamente para imagem, outras coisas podem ser codificadas em base64

Comment: Inclusive injeção de código malicioso

Comment: valeu meu bom!!!